# List.add(x) function replacing all values in the list with x

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new to flutter and I cannot figure out the issue in this code here:

```
List<ToolSteps> toolStepList = List<ToolSteps>.empty(growable: true);
print('my drawStep: ${drawStep.toJsonPencil()}'); // the toJsonPencil is just to print
toolStepList.add(ToolSteps(step: drawStep, toolName: 'test'));
toolStepList.forEach((element) {print(element.toJson());});
```

So the print functions return the same element multiple times, as if my .add is not adding at the end of the list but replacing the whole list with the value i am giving it.
Here are some prints if that helps:

The first time I call the add function:

```
I/flutter ( 4463): my drawStep: {path: [{x: 153, y: 454}], strokeWidth: 20, colorInfo: {colorPrimary: f44336, colorSecondary: ffffff, opacityPrimary: ff, opacitySecondary: ff}}
I/flutter ( 4463): {toolName: pencil, step: {path: [{x: 153, y: 454}], strokeWidth: 20, colorInfo: {colorPrimary: f44336, colorSecondary: ffffff, opacityPrimary: ff, opacitySecondary: ff}}}
```

the second time I call the add function:

```
I/flutter ( 4463): my drawStep: {path: [{x: 868, y: 436}], strokeWidth: 20, colorInfo: {colorPrimary: f44336, colorSecondary: ffffff, opacityPrimary: ff, opacitySecondary: ff}}
I/flutter ( 4463): {toolName: pencil, step: {path: [{x: 868, y: 436}], strokeWidth: 20, colorInfo: {colorPrimary: f44336, colorSecondary: ffffff, opacityPrimary: ff, opacitySecondary: ff}}}
I/flutter ( 4463): {toolName: pencil, step: {path: [{x: 868, y: 436}], strokeWidth: 20, colorInfo: {colorPrimary: f44336, colorSecondary: ffffff, opacityPrimary: ff, opacitySecondary: ff}}}
```

You notice that my first value where the path was x:153 and y:454 got replaced by the new value. I cannot figure out why it does that. And these are the only places where modify the toolStepList. Would really appreciate help or clues.

I tried to create another list of Integers just in case and the same calls work, it just happens when the Type I pass to my list is of ToolSteps in this case

The function to add to the list is called in a gesture detector onPanEnd method:

```
onPanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
print('my drawStep: ${drawStep.toJsonPencil()}'); // the toJsonPencil is just to print
toolStepList.add(ToolSteps(step: drawStep, toolName: 'pencil'));
toolStepList.forEach((element) {print(element.toJson());});
```

}

Comment: please update the code, and show us how did you add the seconde time to the list

Comment: Hi, i add the second item to the list with the aid of a gesture detector onPanEnd function. Everytime i call the function it does what i just showed. I will update the code if that helps

Comment: @GNassro i added the code. Everytime i call panend it adds to the list

Comment: Remember that [the best way to show a problem](/help/how-to-ask) is to show a true [mcve]. That is: show just enough code that if someone else copies and run it, they too see the same problem you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ToolSteps step attribute value is a reference to drawStep, so if you change drawsStep it will change in all places where it's used.
Instead of passing in the same drawStep variable you should initialize your Step inside inside the ToolSteps constructor like this:

```
onPanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
toolStepList.add(ToolSteps(step: Step(path: x,y from details, strokewidth: value from details, colorinfo: value from details, etc...), toolName: 'test'));
}
```

or create a new Step variable every time the gesture detector method is called, like this

```
onPanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
var newDrawStep= -whatever you fetch from details-
toolStepList.add(ToolSteps(step: newDrawStep, toolName: 'pencil'));
}
```

Comment: I CANNOT THANK YOU ENOUGH! i went everywhere and you answered it just like that without even knowing the rest of the code. I really cannot thank you enough. Thanks thanks thanks!!! (i still do not know how the reference part works but i did the second solution you listed and it worked)

Comment: Your welcome!
If you're interested, here is a nice explanation. It is for java, but the idea is the same in Dart as well AFAIK.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference